# mongodb update filtrando con una variable

Tags: mongodb, update

Quiero hacer un update buscando la persona por el id que está en una variable.
Tiene que ser de esa manera, el id por parámetro.

```js
var identificador = db.Personas.find({nombre:"Juan"}, {_id:1})
db.Personas.update({_id: identificador}, {$set:{apellido: "Perez"}})

WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

¿Que estaré haciendo mal?
Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema está en que el método [`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html) de [MongoDB](https://mongodb.com) devuelve un [cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/#read-operations-cursors) que no es más que una referencia o puntero a los documentos que concuerdan con el filtro de búsqueda. Por lo tanto la variable `identificador` no es un valor sino un conjunto de valores (un cursor).

Puedes verificar esto haciendo lo siguiente:

```js
var mi_cursor =  db.Personas.find({nombre:"Juan"}, {_id:1});
while(mi_cursor.hasNext()) {
  print(toJson(mi_cursor.next()));
}
```

**SOLUCIÓN**

Suponiendo que sólo hay un documento en la colección con el campo `nombre` establecido a `Juan`. Una forma de lograr lo que te propones es obtener el valor del campo `_id` de la siguiente forma:

```js
var identificador;
var mi_cursor =  db.Personas.find({nombre:"Juan"}, {_id:1});
while(mi_cursor.hasNext()) {
  identificador = mi_cursor.next()._id;
}

db.Personas.update({_id: identificador}, {$set:{apellido: "Perez"}});
```

Sin embargo, esto no es lo que se acostumbra para realizar este tipo de operaciones.

Si existe más de un documento en la colección con el valor del campo `nombre` establecido en `Juan`, entonces, al iterar el cursor, se almacenará en la variable `identificador` el último documento de la lista de coincidencias.

Lo usual en este caso es usar el método [`findOne()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) para que MongoDB nos devuelva efectivamente 1 sólo documento (en este caso devolverá el primer documento que se coincida con el filtro de búsqueda), de esta forma:

```js
var identificador =  db.Personas.findOne({nombre:"Juan"}, {_id:1})._id;
db.Personas.update({_id: identificador}, {$set:{apellido: "Perez"}});
```

Como se observa, dado que el método `findOne()` devuelve un documento, puedo directamente aplicar `._id` sobre dicho documento y almacenar su valor en la variable `identificador`.

**Alternativas**

Otra forma de hacer la actualización sería usando el método [`findOneAndUpdate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/), que realiza la operación de forma atómica, sobre el primer documento que coincida con el criterio de búsqueda:

```js
var updated = db.Personas.findOneAndUpdate({nombre: "Juan"}, {$set: {apellido: "Pérez"}}, {returnNewDocument: true});
```

De esta forma estarás actualizando un documento (el primero que coincida con el filtro) cuyo campo `nombre` contenga el valor `Juan`. En la variable `updated` se almacena el nuevo documento actualizado (ver que hemos usado la opción `returnNewDocument` establecida a `true`.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Excelente explicación. Para mi caso se ajustó muy bien <br/>
>var identificador =  db.Personas.findOne({nombre:"Juan"}, {_id:1})._id;
>db.Personas.update({_id: identificador}, {$set:{apellido: "Perez"}});<br/>
Muchas gracias!!<br/>
¿Donde das clases?